# error while parsing JSON using GSON and how to access inner elements of JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this JSON

```
{"A":"valA",
"B":["valB"],
"C":"valC",
"D":"valD",
"data":[{
    "data1":"dval1",
    "data2":"dval2",
    "data3":"dval3",
        "data4":"dval4",}],
"F":"valF"}
```

Java Object:

```
public class ABCDObject {
        private String A;
        private String B;
        private String C;
        private String D;
        private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(){
                {
                        add("data1");
                        add("data2");
                        add("data3");
                        add("data4");
                        }
                };
        private String F;

        //getters for the above A,B,C,D, and F 
                public List<String> getData() {
                return data;
        }
```

Main class

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        ABCDObject abcdObj = gson.fromJson(response, ABCDObject.class);
```

I am trying to access value of C as

```
abcdObj.getC();
```

I am getting the error
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string         but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 9 column 17

Another question is how to access the value of data--> data1 and so on

Comment: Shouldn't this `"data4":"dval4",}],`  be turned to that `"data4":"dval4"}],`

Comment: @Jakub actually it is without the last comma before closing brace

Comment: Your data was not conforming JSON syntax. Once you make your data conform it - this data needs to represent the class which you want to parse it to. You get an error on `column 17` because it is the `[` which tells the parser that B has a value which is an array. In your ABCDObject class B is a string. An array and a string are different things.

Comment: i have corrected the String B. What about data array object, how do i define it as array of object

Comment: If you can, switch to Jackson - it's far better than gson. yes, being made by google doesn't make thing awesome ;)

Comment: @dantuch what makes Jackson better than Gson? I'm a Gson maintainer; we've done a lot to make it faster and simpler so I think your advice is out of date.

Comment: @Jesse Wilson, ah, nice to meet you ;) So - can gson serialize given object with his inherited fields without need to use some builders? Jackson does it out of the box in single line method. So what are the benefits of using gson in such situation, is it way faster or what?

Comment: @dantuch yeah, Gson takes 2 lines of code, though I don't think that makes it worse. Gson's main advantage is its simplicity, small size, efficiency and predictability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON doesn't match the object, including:

- `B` is an array in the JSON, and a String in `ABCDObject`
- `data` is an array of objects with four properties in the JSON, and an array of strings in `ABCDObject`.

---

*Edit with example*

Using the following two classes, and fixing the mal-formed JSON (the spurious comma after data4), this works as expected.

**Data** - holds each element of the "data" array, each data object has four data fields.

```
public class Data {
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    private String data3;
    private String data4;
    // Plus getters, setters, toString
}
```

**JsonHolder** - encapsulates the entire JSON object.

```
import java.util.List;

public class JsonHolder {
    private String A;
    private List<String> B;
    private String C;
    private String D;
    private List<Data> data;
    private String F;
    // Plus getters, setters, toString
}
```

**sanity check**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonHolder json = gson.fromJson(JSON_STRING, JsonHolder.class);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**output**

```
JsonHolder{A='valA', B=[valB], C='valC', D='valD', data=[Data{data1='dval1', data2='dval2', data3='dval3', data4='dval4'}], F='valF'}
```

Note that attempting to work around the malformed JSON by [using `JsonReader.setLenient(true)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) won't work in this case; it only handles extra commas at the end of an array (collection), not in an object itself as your example JSON contains.

Comment: how do I make it array of object, do i need to create another class for that

Comment: @user1425918 You'd need another class to encapsulate that, with properties `data1`, `data2`, etc. if that's the JSON, but your Java code indicates it's just a string array. I don't know which is correct.

Comment: JSON is the correct one, I would try with creating new class and come back on this

Comment: @user1425918 Updated with example.

Comment: it has worked perfectly after creating new class and changing type of B.